# Node JS project loading local text\sql file works loacly but not when deployed to AWS as a lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, fs

I have a project in Node JS which execute SQL queries.
So I have added the SQL queries as files to the project like this:
query1.sql
query2.sql
query3.sql
And so forth...

I'm using a function to load the files content which looks like this:

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

```
function getConetntByFileName(fileName) {
    try {
        //let abolute_path = path.join(__dirname,fileName);
        let abolute_path = path.relative(process.cwd(), fileName)
        //const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8')
        const data = fs.readFileSync(abolute_path, 'utf8')
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        let msg = `Error in getConetntByFileName :${err}`
        console.error(msg)
        throw new Error(msg);
    }
}
```

getConetntByFileName receives the full file's path and needs to return it's content
It works locally every time but when I deploys it I get the error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[file path]/query1.sql'

I tried many versions to catch the relative path, the absolute path (you can the commented rows in the code).

I can't figure out why it works locally but can't find the files when it's deployed to AWS.

Comment: I tried adding 'use strict' and in the yml file : 
package:
  individually: false
  include:
    - src/**

I keep getting same results....
I tried absolute and relative path...
I'm really lost here...

Comment: OK - found the problem...
My local environment is windows and I have misconfigured the file path folder name with one uppercase letter instead of lower.
Windows is case insensitive while AWS is not!!!....